# В JS заметил какую-то странность в работе при связке с PHP - не работают \n и \r (переносы строк)

Tags: javascript

код php:

```
print "<script>alert('Первая строка\n\rВторая строка')</script>";
print "<script>alert('Первая строка<br>Вторая строка')</script>";
```

Варинт первый вообще не срабатывает алертом
Вариант 2 отображает сам тег 
Но если код вставить напрямую в HTML, то первый вариант срабатывает корректно.
Как быть? У меня там переменные нужные. Прерывать php-код ради отладочного алерта нецелесообразно.
Что за недочёт и почему такое происходит?

Comment: А вы посмотрите на получившийся невалидный скрипт.

Comment: Наверное надо так: `print "<script>alert('Первая строка\\nВторая строка')</script>";`, но вообще `alert` это очень специальная фукция и не факт, что она покажет переносы строк.

Comment: `alert('Первая строка \n\r Вторая строка')` ну такое вот отлично работает), но `<br>` `alert` не умеет, там нет `html`

Comment: @ThisMan, а почему у меня не работает?

Comment: Потому что `php` сам выводит перенос строчки, вам посоветовали выше экранировать обратный слеш, это будет решением

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Спасибо Вам! Всё сработало! Как всё оказалось просто.

Comment: @ThisMan, Спасибо. Теперь понял почему не работало. Php "рубил" скрипт.